# Missed semicolon You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I have an Angular 14 project. One of the tasks is to convert the default font to our company's specific font. We are using Angular material components and styling. As such, I not only want to specify the default font on the body element but I want all of the material components to use that font as well. I'm following the material theming guide, and specifically https://material.angular.io/guide/typography.

The error above happens during compilation when I specify the our custom font which has the form of 'OurFont:sans'. That is the name of the font in the css downloaded from the company CDN. If I remove the :sans, then the compile works.

snippet from _light.scss that fails:

```
$ourFont-sans-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'OurFont:sans',
);
```

this works:

```
$ourFont-sans-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'ourFont',
);
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, though I thought I attempted it before. Put the font-family name(s) in parenthesis like:

```
$ourFont-sans-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: ('ourFont:sans'),
);
```